# How do I enable the wireless adapter on a Lenovo x100e?

Tags: wireless, 12.10

I'm very fresh to Ubuntu and I just downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo x100e computer. I'm having issues with my wireless adapter. It says the adapter was turned off by a hardware switch. The issue is that my laptop has no hardware switch for wireless!

The way I used to enable/disable wireless was through <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd> keys. when I tried to turn it on from the network setting, it didn't allow me. It keeps turning off straight away. If anyone has any advice or help to give I'd be very grateful.

My wireless adapter is the following: Realtek 802.11bgn

Looking forward to hearing from you and thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The hardware switch may be referring the the Fn + F5 keyboard shortcut. 
Also, check your computer's bios to see if wifi is disabled or enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my Dell Vostro 3500.
I verified the BIOS setup, wireless is enabled. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> didn't help.
I create a Ubuntu Startup Disk from my Sony Vaio; for which wireless works fine.
When I boot the Vostro 3500 from that USB the Vostro's wireless work fine.  I re-intalled Ubuntu on the Vostro using wireless connection.

When I reboot the Vostro on its own, the wireless option isn't available in drop down list from a the right click of network icon.

Below 'Enable Networking' was 'Enable Wireless'.  Days ago I disabled 'Enable Wireless' from the drop down list and that option stopped being listed.

The 'Network' option under 'System' only shows 'Wired', and 'Network proxy'.  'Wireless' cannot be add either.

From 'Edit Connection' of that drop list I added my Wireless connection, didn't help.

The message I get is 'No proprietary drivers are in use on this system'.
The identified driver listed is 'Broadcom STA wireless driver'

Under 'Licence: Proprietary' line the text reads:

> This package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver for use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based hardware.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 32-bit

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to enable it, very easy, I am using broadcom adapter.
Go to Synaptic package manager, find precise-updates then mark `bcmwl` for installation, then apply and walaaaa its done.

Answer (score 0):

Try an reinstall bcmwl

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```